# How to use variable for user input and then use the same one for data processing. Python

Tags: python, sockets

This is my code:

```
user_input = input("What port would you like to use? ")

def output(name):
   print(f'Set Port {name}')
output(user_input)

Hello123 = input(f'Please Choose A IP Address ')
if Hello123 == '127.0.0.1':
   print('WARNING PLEASE BE SURE YOU KNOW WHAT YOUR DOING BEFORE YOU SET THIS')

def output(ipaddr):
    print(f'Set Ip {ipaddr}')
output(Hello123)

HOST = (f'{ipaddr}')
PORT = (f'{name}')

server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)  
server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1) 
server_socket.bind((HOST, PORT))`
```

I am creating a socket in python and I want it to be ipaddr for {HOST} and user input I also want to do the same with PORT and {name}

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: I want it to use the user input recieved in the beginning (IP address and port) and have the program use that as the data because right now it just says I have Incomplete code...

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: The question is too ambiguous. Can you add the error you are facing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below should work:

```
port = int(input("What port would you like to use? "))
host = input("What host would you like to use? ")
server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)  
server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1) 
server_socket.bind((host, port))
```